# How to send looping items into ajax in Django? {% for item in items %} {{ item }} {% endfor %} How to pass all items in a single call of ajax?

Tags: python, django, ajax

[image]

All of the names need to call using ajax!

Code for ajax I have tried.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).on('submit','#form',function(e){

            e.preventDefault();
            alert("No reload")

            $.ajax({
               type:'POST',
                url:'add-result',
                data:{
                   subject:$('#subject').val(),
                   **//How to get all names from loop here?**
                   names:$('#names').val(),
                    test_score:$('#test_score').val(),
                    exam_score:$('#exam_score').val(),
                    class:$('#class').val(),
                    exam_term:$('#exam_term').val(),
                    exam_date:$('#exam_date').val(),

                    csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
                           success:function (){
                     alert("Here")
                   },
                },
                success:function (){
                   alert("Working !")
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: If queryset `names` has a length greater than 1 you will have duplicate identifiers for id's such as `exam_score` and `exam_term`. If the length is equal to 1, then there is no need for iteration.

Comment: use `each` to iterate through your trs and get relevant data from td using `.find()` and then  append the values inside json array .

Comment: Please elaborate. Thank you for your answer

Comment: can you show your html code in text ? @technologyissuenepal